# Using Javascript Api Notification In Angular being unable to show image of directory path

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, customization

Good day developers Im trying to retrieve a local image from my assets folder and display it on my new Notification object generated by Web Notification API, but cant receive the image.

In my assets folder i have a image with extension jpeg

[image]

Also was suggested to add this configuration to my angular.json file
[image]

then on my method for showing notifications i exposed this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NotificationService {
  public grantesPermission: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.grantesPermission = false;
  }
  public async result()...
  public showError()...

  public showNotification(): void {
    const notification = new Notification('', {
      body: 'This is a JavaScript Notification API demo',
      icon: '../../assets/flor.jpeg',========>. Here the problem
                     OR
      icon:'/assets/flor.jpeg' 
    });

   
    setTimeout(() => {
      notification.close();
    }, 1000000000000 * 1000);

  }
}
```

the notification shows up ,without the image of the icon path And in console i receive this error
[image]

```
GET http://localhost:5001/assets/flor.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

How could i improve this situation ?

Comment: are you sure it's jpeg and not jpg?

Comment: yes is jpeg....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
icon: '/assets/flor.jpeg'
```

Comment: same problem ...image not shown

Comment: it looks like notification is showing chrome icon, mby you need specify web icon in manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have `src/assets` path inside assets in angular.json file.[image]

This could be the problem. If not I don't see any problem with the code. The exact code works for me.

Comment: same problem remains